# One of my IBM Cloud Continuous Delivery pipeline jobs stopped working. Did something change in the pipeline?

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

One of my test jobs has a line similar to this one...

```
export APP_URL=http://$(cf app ${CF_APP} | grep urls: | awk '{print $2}')
```

... which was copied from one of the toolchain example templates. Recently, this has stopped working. Has something changed in the environment where pipeline jobs are run?

Answer (score 5):

Over time, the tools/applications which are available to run from pipeline job scripts have become significantly outdated, when compared to what developers typically find on their desktops. We have begun the process of providing more recent versions of these tools.

One example of this is the Cloud Foundry command line (i.e. "cf"), which was recently updated. The cf command was refactored after v23 and its output format changed slightly. Instead of "urls:" it now uses "routes:", so to fix the situation above, you would need to change the line to...

```
export APP_URL=http://$(cf app ${CF_APP} | grep -e urls: -e routes: | awk '{print $2}')
```

We are also updating our templates to match this new pattern.